# Symfony3 FOSOAuthServerBundle: Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I am trying  build a rest api on Symfony3  and  using a combination of FOSOAuthServerBundle , JMSerializer and FOSUserBundle.
I have the configurations set up to the best of my knowledge i however cannot get the api to  return a token.

it in fact always returns 
        {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

despite providing the grant_type key and value

so i did a bunch of digging  and tried suggestions on this [FOSOAuthServerBundle: Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436958/fosoauthserverbundle-invalid-grant-type-parameter-or-parameter-missing) and also this [FOSOAuthServerBundle + FOSRestBundle + CamelCase = Not authenticating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466402/fosoauthserverbundle-fosrestbundle-camelcase-not-authenticating)  i still could not get it to work.
from my findings i probably need to to disable the body listener which converts underscored keys to camel  in either FOSRestBundle or the JMSerializer Bundle 
i however have no clue on how to do either
I would appreciate pointers in the right direction on how to resolve the issue

my config.yml foss section looks like this

```
# FOSRest Configuration
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    zone:
             - { path: ^/api }
    allowed_methods_listener: true

    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'text/html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }

    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```

security.yml look like this the

security:
        encoders:
           UserBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

```
    role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
                    id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:


        authenticate

           pattern: ^/
           form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    #csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
           logout:       true
           anonymous:    true

          #auth api stuff
        oauth_token:
              pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
              security: false
        api_doc:
              pattern: ^/api/doc
              security: false
        api:
            pattern:  ^/api
            fos_oauth:    true
            stateless:    true

        #end
    access_control:
              - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
              - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
              - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
              - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

              #api
              - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
```

Comment: You should post some of the code that you are using so you can be helped.

Comment: see update contains code from the config.yml and security.yml

Comment: You've setup your security to only permit authenticated users to access the path `/api`, so the user needs to authenticate by accessing `/login` first with username and password, and in the same session/request make the api call (GET or POST).

Comment: the route to authenticate via the api is this  /oauth/v2/token and it is not protected by the firewalls ,i can post to it fine  but the response is never the expected access token , that  would allow you to access the  protected /api   routes it always return  "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"  even when its proivided

Comment: I'm quite sure you are sending a json request. I don't know why but it's not supported. Try to send the data as "form data".